# InSSider max rate

Tags: wireless-networking

I have inissider network analyzer tool running on my window 7 machine.  I also have 2 different networks running in my house. Each network is on different router.  When i run inSsider it shows that i am connected to one of those network but max rate for one is 156 and second one is 144.  Should it not be same? 
I dont think i understand what is going on here.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; the two devices broadcasting networks in your home are different and have different capabilities. Read on if you want more details.

You don't mention the vendor or models of the devices running in your home, but based on the information in the information included we can tell a few things.

Let me address the lower entry first with the max data rate of 144. This is a 802.11n device capable of two spatial streams and running a 20MHz wide channel in 2.4GHz with a short guard interval. At MCS 15 the data rate for this configuration is 144.4Mbps.

The 156 data rate device is a bit more of a mystery. I would call this one easy as well, but the 802.11 column in your screenshot is showing "n" as the only value. This leads me to a few possibilities.

Most likely inSSIDer has a bit of a split personality (I haven't used the particular version you are running) because of a problem in the code or an oversight by the developers. By this I mean that it is recognizing 802.11ac data rates, but is not showing that this is an 802.11ac network. Or if your client is only 802.11n, it may be working as intended and showing the networks only as capable as your client can utilize.

If this assumption about a problem with inSSIDer is true, then this is an 802.11ac access point with support for two spatial streams running a 20MHz wide channel in 2.4GHz with a long guard interval. At MCS 8 w/2 spatial streams (802.11ac MCS values don't include the number of spatial streams so never exceed 9) with this configuration the maximum data rate is 156Mbps. MCS 9 is not supported by the standard for two spatial streams with a 20MHz wide channel.

If my assumption about inSSIDer is not true, then this brings us to one of the other two options I can see. Either your second device is using proprietary extensions to 802.11n or it has some serious issues with it's firmware.

What do I mean about proprietary extensions? Sometimes once the next 802.11 performance amendment is being drafted, vendors of consumer devices will "back port" features from the new amendment into their products to give them a "performance" edge in their marketing. This performance edge also typically requires that you also use their adapter that understands the proprietary extensions, otherwise it will only perform like a "normal" device. For example, at one point 802.11g devices with MIMO support (a feature from 802.11n) were popular to exceed the 54Mbps max data rate.

Answer (score 1):

I've used InSSIDer and other tools for quite some time and have had similar questions.

I believe an access point's max rate depends on the chips and other hardware used on the devices circuit boards. Based on the mac addresses, the first AP is either Belkin, has some Belkin components or is equipment manufactured by Belkin under another name. The latter two are becoming more common lately as Belkin's Wi-Fi device sales have declined somewhat. The second device shows to be Cisco/Linksys.

For quite a while Netgear wireless equipment had the best max rate for consumer equipment. It's been a while but I'm thinking this was something like 255 or 345. Lately I've seen other manufacturers have max rates of 450 (Belkin and Ubiquiti) and 600 (Linksys).

In my Wi-Fi testing, the maximum wireless throughput I have seen is about 500 Mbps. This is laptop to server, not internet speed. I'm not an expert on the hardware components but for the last couple of years I have shopped for my company with max rate in mind, though this information is not always available.

I think Wi-Fi equipment manufacturers are finally improving their equipment's max rate for maximum throughput due to savvy consumers expecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Ive just installed inSSider on my laptop here at work, we run both ruckus and unifi AP's (we are going all unifi in coming month or two.

with regards to the max rates ive noticed that im seeing from my unifi AP's the rates for 20Mhz (2g) are 216.7 and for 40Mhz (5g) are 600

and on Ruckus AP's i have a 20Mhz (2g) are 144.4 and max rate for 80Mhz 5g of 866.7

Ive just change my test Unifi AP to 80Mhz (5g) and max rate is 1300

Comment: There are many variables affecting the actual max transfer rates. Above you're comparing Unifi's 40MHz bandwidth to Ruckus's 80MHz - twice as wide -> twice the bandwidth; in principle. The channel has an effect, which you see fastest in the uber-congested 2.4GHz spectrum. Assume your Ruckus is bcasting on 2.4GHz channel 1 where a lot of other APs are bcasting as well; but your Unifi is bcasting on 2.4GHz channel 11 which is practically empty - Ruckus will show worse performance due to same-channel interference. A lot of things in WiFi aren't quite what they appear :-)